# Confidence Intervals using Pivotal Quantities

Tags: statistics

I am stuck on this question:

In a study of the amount of contaminants in drinking water, six samples were ran through a lab.  The six readings, in parts per million, were $9.8, 9.43, 8.97, 9.33, 9.14,$ and $9.55$.  Estimate the population variance $\sigma^2$ for readings by deriving a $90$% confidence interval using a pivotal quantity.

I'm not sure how to approach this question.  Finding the sample variance should be straightforward using the six samples, but I'm not sure if I can assume the sample follows a Normal Distribution, as it doesn't state that in the question.  Therefore I'm not sure if I can use a pivotal quantity of the Z-Score formula, or $\frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$.

It'll be great if I can get some pointers as to how to determine the pivotal quantity for similar types of questions.  Thanks!

Comment: For a formal discussion of [pivotal quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity), see this Wikipedia link. The 'pivot' consists of solving the inequality of an event of known probability to isolate the unknown parameter. One of the displayed equations in my Answer illustrates that procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most practical purposes it is not feasible to get a useful CI for $\sigma^2$ from only $n = 6$ observations.
My guess is this is a drill problem and you're intended
to assume normality of the population and to assume you can get useful
information from such a small sample.

Suppose data are normal and both population mean $\mu$ and population variance $\sigma^2$ are unknown, $\mu$ is estimated by $\bar X$ and $\sigma^2$ is estimated by
$S^.$ Then a useful pivotal quantity is

$$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$$

Suppose you want a 90% confidence interval for $\mu$ based on your $n = 6$ observations. Then the values
$L = 1.145$ and $U=11.070$ cut 5% of the probability from the lower and upper tails of the $\mathsf{Chisq}(5),$ respectively. These cut-off values can be found from tables of the chi-squared distribution or by using software. In R statistical software, we have the following computation:

```
qchisq(c(.05,.95), 5)
[1]  1.145476 11.070498
```

Thus 
$$0.90 = P\left(L \le \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \le U\right)
= P\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{U} \le \sigma^2 \le \frac{(n-1)S^2}{L}\right),$$
so that the desired 90% confidence interval is of
the form
$$\left( \frac{(n-1)S^2}{U},\; \frac{(n-1)S^2}{L}\right) = (0.0393, 0.3801).$$

For your data, the computation in R amounts to the following:

```
x = c(9.8, 9.43, 8.97, 9.33, 9.14, 9.55)
df = length(x) - 1
v = var(x)  
[1] 0.08708
df*v/qchisq(c(.95,.05), df)
[1]  0.03932976 0.38010392
```

Notice that the point estimate $S^2 = 0.0871$ of $\sigma^2$ is included in this confidence interval. However, owing to the skewness of the distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(5),$ the point estimate is not at the *center* of the interval. 
[That is, unlike a CI for $\mu$ based on the symmetrical t distribution and $\bar X,$ this CI for $\sigma^2$ is *not* of the form 
'point estimate plus or minus a margin of error'.]

If you want a 95% CI for the population
standard deviation $\sigma,$ then take square roots of both endpoints of the CI for $\sigma^2.$

Answer (score 0):

You use a pivotal quantity to approximate the moments of the underlying distribution. The pivotal quantity of the Z-score is using the Central Limit Theorem:

Suppose $\{X_1, X_2, \ldots\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $E[X_i] = µ$ and $Var[X_i] = σ^2 < ∞$. Then as n approaches infinity, the random variables $√n(\overline{x} − µ)$ converge in distribution to a normal $N(0,σ^2)$.

So the only assumptions you are making on the data are the ones given in CLT.

Comment: CLT here for a sample size of $6$?

Comment: ok, but I can see that the sample size is too small for the CLT to hold.  Does that mean I have to use another pivotal quantity?

Comment: CLT is true asymptotically. So for any finite sample size, it is still an approximation. Unless you have been given other pivotals to work with, you should be fine using the one you stated (which is based on CLT).

Comment: In what way would the expression stated in the Question be "fine" in obtaining a CI for $\sigma^2?$ Does it contain a statistic that can be used to estimate $\sigma^2?$ Also, would you recommend the gamma distributed mean of a sample of (finite) size $n = 6$ from an exponential population as having a useful "approximation" to normal?